# Deleting Nodes, linked list not working

Tags: c, linked-list

I can't figure out how to properly delete and reorganize a node. Can someone explain what I did wrong and how I can fix it?

I tried reading other posts but I can't find one compared to mine.

```
printf("Enter index number of person to be deleted=\n");
scanf("%d", &index_del);
t = head;
while(t->index != index_del)
{
  t = t->next;
}
t1 = t->next;
t->next = t1->next;  ////////////////////breaks here somewhere
free(t1);
break;
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `while(t->index!=index_del-1)`? And you'll have to make special provision for removing the first element (unless you have a separate 'empty' first element). And you should do out-of-bounds checking. And what's that `break` breaking out of?

Comment: breaks out of a case loop, this is case 3 used for deleting nodes

Answer (score 1):

```
struct node *tmp, **pp;
int index_del;

scanf("%d", &index_del);

for (pp = &head; *pp; )
        if ((*pp)->index != index_del) {pp = &(*pp)->next; continue; }
        tmp = *pp;
        *pp = tmp->next;
        free(tmp);
        }
```

- this will delete the node even if it is located at the head of the list
- and it will also delete multiple nodes with the value `index_del`, if these should exist

The trick is here: the only thing that needs to be changed is the pointer that points to the node to be deleted.. This could either be the `head` pointer outside the list or one of the `->next` pointers from within the list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to distinguish two cases:

if index_del is 0 you have to set head to head->next, else you have to set the next-member of the **previous** item:

```
printf("Enter index number of person to be deleted=\n");
scanf("%d", &index_del);
if (index_del == 0)
{
  t = head->next;
  free(head);
  head = t;
}
else
{
t = head;
while(t->index != index_del)
{
  p = t;
  t = t->next;
}
// t is the item to delete, p is the item before t
p->next = t->next;
free(t);
break;
```